# counting and probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need help figuring out this exercise. I am stuck on it and am not sure how to get it started. Any help is appreciated.

Exercise: An instructor gives an exam with 14 questions. Students are allowed to choose any 10 to answer. I am stuck on part B of this exercise. Part B states, suppose 6 questions require proof and 8 do not. How many groups of 10 questions contains at most three 3 that require proof? I am not sure how to build the necessary equation to answer this.

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only $8$ questions that do not require proof, any set of $10$ questions must have at least $2$ that do require proof.

- How many ways are there to choose $2$ questions that require proof and $8$ that do not?
- How many ways are there to choose $3$ questions that require proof and $7$ that do not?

The sum of those two numbers is your answer.

Comment: Hey Brian, if it is not too much to ask, would you mind walking me through one of these bullet points. I still can't figure this stuff out. Thanks.

Comment: @Tony: Let me ask first: can you tell me how many different sets there are of $3$ questions that require proof? Never mind the other $7$ questions for now.

Comment: Would that be 10C3?

Comment: @Tony: No, because there are only $6$ questions that require proof. Thus, you’re choosing $3$ from $6$, not from $10$, and it’s $\binom63$, not $\binom{10}3$. Now how many ways are there to choose $7$ questions out of the $8$ that do not require proof?

Comment: Okay, so if I have 8 question that do not require proof then in order to choose 7 question I would need to do $\binom{8}7$

Comment: Brian, do we have 7 because we have a total of 10 question and we are just subtracting 3 from to to get 7? Is that correct?

Comment: @Tony: Right. So there are $\binom63=20$ ways to choose $3$ questions that require proof, and $\binom87=8$ ways to choose $7$ questions that do not require proof. Any of the $20$ sets of $3$ can be combined with any of the $8$ sets of $7$ to form a set of $10$, so there are $20\cdot8=160$ such sets. Now apply the same reasoning to the other bullet point to count the rest of the possibilities.

Comment: Okay, I think I am starting to get this. I am going to copy this and make some note to make sure I fully understand it. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Tony: You’re very welcome.